# How to capture specific blocks of lines in text with regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-group

I'm using the Notepad++ Find and Replace tool with regex.

A snippet of the text I'm working with looks like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nec dignissim neque. Maecenas condimentum tellus at mauris dictum, nec accumsan augue lacinia. Phasellus condimentum erat ante, a cursus tortor ultricies eu. Curabitur auctor sem ac dignissim interdum.

Me --- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Her --- Curabitur suscipit arcu justo, et scelerisque nunc commodo ac.

Me --- Nunc luctus, ligula vel porta convallis, augue mauris lobortis quam, ut volutpat sapien felis a erat.

Her --- Sed id pellentesque risus.    

Curabitur vehicula vitae est vel tempus. In quam augue, condimentum et mauris pellentesque, dignissim tempor libero. Morbi placerat posuere velit nec varius. Praesent vitae quam egestas, ultrices tortor sit amet, porttitor mauris. Etiam hendrerit vitae ante vitae posuere. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
```

What I want to be able to do is capture the text starting from "Me --- Lorem ipsum..." and until "...pellentesque risus." So that I can put a LaTeX formatting on it, which would result in:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nec dignissim neque. Maecenas condimentum tellus at mauris dictum, nec accumsan augue lacinia. Phasellus condimentum erat ante, a cursus tortor ultricies eu. Curabitur auctor sem ac dignissim interdum.

\begin{fancyquote}
Me --- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Her --- Curabitur suscipit arcu justo, et scelerisque nunc commodo ac.

Me --- Nunc luctus, ligula vel porta convallis, augue mauris lobortis quam, ut volutpat sapien felis a erat.

Her --- Sed id pellentesque risus.    
\end{fancyquote} 

Curabitur vehicula vitae est vel tempus. In quam augue, condimentum et mauris pellentesque, dignissim tempor libero. Morbi placerat posuere velit nec varius. Praesent vitae quam egestas, ultrices tortor sit amet, porttitor mauris. Etiam hendrerit vitae ante vitae posuere. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
```

The thing is, the text blocks could either start with "Me ---" or "Her ---" and they could end either way too.

So far I have (\nMe ---|Her ---), which starts the grouping properly with either option, but I'm having trouble trying to terminate the selection with regex. What I want to say is, something like, match anything (including newline) except when you see a newline and then NOT ("Her ---" OR "Me ---").

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I think I have the beginning:
(\nMe ---|Her ---)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

Find what:

```
((?:^(?:Me|Her) ---.*\s+)+)
```

Replace with:

```
\\begin{fancyquote}\n\1\\end{fancyquote}\n\n
```

Result:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean nec dignissim neque. Maecenas condimentum tellus at mauris dictum, nec accumsan augue lacinia. Phasellus condimentum erat ante, a cursus tortor ultricies eu. Curabitur auctor sem ac dignissim interdum.

\begin{fancyquote}
Me --- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Her --- Curabitur suscipit arcu justo, et scelerisque nunc commodo ac.

Me --- Nunc luctus, ligula vel porta convallis, augue mauris lobortis quam, ut volutpat sapien felis a erat.

Her --- Sed id pellentesque risus.    

\end{fancyquote}

Curabitur vehicula vitae est vel tempus. In quam augue, condimentum et mauris pellentesque, dignissim tempor libero. Morbi placerat posuere velit nec varius. Praesent vitae quam egestas, ultrices tortor sit amet, porttitor mauris. Etiam hendrerit vitae ante vitae posuere. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
```